# how can i checkbox to be checked based on the value in the database .if the status is 1 then the checkbox to be checked

Tags: jquery, yii2

how can i checkbox to be checked based on the value in the database .if the status(is_closed) is 1 then the checkbox to be checked

```
 echo $form->field($model, 'is_closed')->checkbox(['id'=>'checkbox-'.$value->action_status_id,'class'=>"input_class input_checkbox",'value'=>$value['is_closed'],
    'onClick'=> new yii\web\JsExpression("
        var tableUsed = 'status';
        var obj=$(this);
        var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
        var dInput= $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
           type : 'POST',
           data : {'id':id[1]},
           url: '".Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl("actions/setting-checkbox-update")."',
           success: function(data){
            var tableRow = obj.closest('tr'); 
            tableRow.find('.saving').show();
            setTimeout(function(){ tableRow.find('.saving').hide();}, 500);
            stat=JSON.parse(data)
            tableRow.find('.input_checkbox').prop('checked', stat.closed== 1);
          }  
        });
")])->label(FALSE);
```

$value['is_closed] have value 1 or 0 based on the database value

Comment: where are you trying to load this value is it the edit form? as Yii automatically assigns the value to the input if you have set it before sending the model to the view either by manually setting like `$model->is_closed=1` or if you are selecting the existing records in case of edit , it will set automatically if the value is saved in the database table.

Comment: and you are using `$value` for the column `is_closed` ? isnt the value coming from the same model you are populating the form with `$model`?

Comment: yes it is in the edit form...$model->is_closed=1 yes i tried that one its not working

Comment: remove `'value'=>$value['is_closed']` from the `checkbox()` function

Comment: i removed that 'value'=>$value['is_closed'] .Now all are checked if the is_closed is 0 also the checkbox is checked

Comment: strange you need to add all the form fields of type checkboxes to see if they are also using the same column? to be checked

Comment: yes same column